# My contacts Form.java, the image row in the table does not appear when log in

Tags: java, mysql, arrays

What should I do:java&Netbeans, MySQL
this array to Show Contacts Information in the Jtable of the Form When login with the account

[image: The Form]

```
ContactQuery cq=new ContactQuery(); 
ArrayList<Contact> ctList=cq.contactList();
//`id`, `fname`, `lname`, `groupc`, `phone`, `email`, `address`, `picture`
String[] colNames={"Id","First Name ","Last Name","Group","Phone","Email","Address","Picture"};
Object[][] rows=new Object [ctList.size()][8];
    
for(int i=0;i<ctList.size();i++)
{
    rows[i][0]=ctList.get(i).getId();
    rows[i][1]=ctList.get(i).getFname();
    rows[i][2]=ctList.get(i).getLname();
    rows[i][3]=ctList.get(i).getGroupc();
    rows[i][4]=ctList.get(i).getPhone();
    rows[i][5]=ctList.get(i).getEmail();
    rows[i][6]=ctList.get(i).getAddress();
    
// this show only the (javax.swing.ImageIcon)not the image :What should i do here ?
ImageIcon pic= new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(ctList.get(i).getPicture()).getImage().getScaledInstance(150, 100, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
     rows[i][7]=pic;
     
  }
MyModel mmd=new MyModel(rows, colNames);
jTable1.setModel(mmd);
jTable1.setRowHeight(100);
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setPreferredWidth(150);
```

Comment: What does `MyModel` look like? Consider providing a [mcve]

Comment: MyModel is a pubic class which extends AbstractTableModel and contains the override columns and rows that appears on in the form

Comment: Did you override `getColumnClass` - maybe posted in the in question

Comment: We also need to have a better understanding of how `ContactQuery` is working, so we know how the image is actually been loaded

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're "particular" problem is, there's not enough context to ascertain exactly where you might be having problems, but, I suspect that you're not overriding the `getColumnClass` method of the `AbstractTableModel`, so it doesn't know how it should handle the `ImageIcon`.

[image: Happy]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            List<AnimalItem> items = new ArrayList<>(25);
            items.add(new AnimalItem("Bear", new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/Bear.png"))));
            items.add(new AnimalItem("Kitty", new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/Cat.png"))));
            items.add(new AnimalItem("Doggy", new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/Doggy.png"))));
            items.add(new AnimalItem("Foxy", new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/Fox.png"))));
            items.add(new AnimalItem("Drop bear", new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/Koala.png"))));
            items.add(new AnimalItem("Lion", new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/Lion.png"))));
            items.add(new AnimalItem("Piggy", new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/Pig.png"))));
            items.add(new AnimalItem("Bunny", new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/Rabbit.png"))));
            items.add(new AnimalItem("Raccon", new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/Raccon.png"))));

            AnimalTableModel tableModel = new AnimalTableModel(items);
            JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
            table.setRowHeight(64);
            add(new JScrollPane(table));
        }

    }

    public class AnimalItem {

        private String name;
        private ImageIcon image;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public ImageIcon getImage() {
            return image;
        }

        public AnimalItem(String name, ImageIcon image) {
            this.name = name;
            this.image = image;
        }

    }

    public class AnimalTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private List<AnimalItem> items;
        private String[] columnNames = new String[]{
            "Name",
            "Image"
        };

        public AnimalTableModel(List<AnimalItem> items) {
            this.items = items;
        }

        public void setItems(List<AnimalItem> items) {
            this.items = items;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return items.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            return columnNames[column];
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0: return String.class;
                case 1: return ImageIcon.class;
            }

            return String.class;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            AnimalItem item = items.get(rowIndex);
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    return item.getName();
                case 1:
                    return item.getImage();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

*nb: The images are been loaded directly from the application context (ie they are embedded), so you will need to supply your own images and they will need to be in the `/images` package*